# Science fiction novel about a girl finding girl attached to glass tubes in a glass container

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a futuristic science fiction novel. I can only distinctly remember a few things:

- The book takes place in a society where children are in school until it is decided they are ready, and then taken for a job that is decided by the "government".
- It is about a girl who is taken into the "government building". When she is left alone she wanders around despite being told not to. She finds a girl in a container who is attached to glass tubes.
- The girl escapes the city to the unsafe outskirts and goes on a journey.

Does anyone know the name and author of this story?